# Sorting dict by member

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of dictionary like

```
array[0] = {'id' : 123 , 'number' : 345 , 'zipcode' : 67890}
array[1] ...
```

I used

```
array.sort(key=lambda k: k['number'] , reverse=True)
```

and before

```
array.sort(key= operator.itemgetter('number') , reverse=True)
```

The sorting works but, when i've number like

```
3 34 3456 2 23 234556
```

The sort doesn't change the order cause 3 (if i understand the treatment) equals 3(4) and 3(3456) etc ...

Any idea to improve the key or something like to make the sort better ?

Comment: Are your numbers actually numbers as shown in your example, or strings? If they are strings, they will get sorted lexicographicaly instead of numerically, resulting in the kind of problems you are talking about.

Comment: Could it be that your number fields are actually strings? It almost looks like alphabetical sorting

Comment: Thank you both of you, it was. I get an object through an api function so i didn't know how the object was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have strings as values you need to cast to int:

```
array.sort(key=lambda k: int(k['number']) , reverse=True)
```

When sorting strings of digits `"2" > "100"`. Python compares the two strings character by character, the first higher character will be considered  greater or if all characters are the same up to the length of the shorter string the longer string will be considered greater.

You can see the behaviour using a simple example:

```
In [1]: a = "123"   
In [2]: b = "2"  
In [3]: a > b
Out[3]: False   
In [4]: int(a) > int(b)
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think that it could be string so the "3" is before "34" ...
Dunno how to +rep or something like but you should have more ^^.

EDIT : Edit done and it works great.

Any idea on how to do the same with operator.itemgetter() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sorted instead of sort,t's most common to pass a list into the sorted() function, but in fact it can take as input any sort of iterable collection.

The sorted() function can be customized though optional arguments. The sorted() optional argument reverse=True, e.g. sorted(list, reverse=True), makes it sort backwards.
You try with sorted

`print sorted(array, key=lambda k: k['number'] , reverse=True)`

Example.
`strs = ['aa', 'BB', 'zz', 'CC']
print sorted(strs)  ## ['BB', 'CC', 'aa', 'zz'] (case sensitive)
print sorted(strs, reverse=True)   ## ['zz', 'aa', 'CC', 'BB']`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
print sorted(array, key=lambda k: k['number'] , reverse=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to reproduce the issue you're having, this is the output of an IDLE session for me (Python 3, Windows 64-bit):

```
>>> array = []
>>> array.append({'id' : 123 , 'number' : 345 , 'zipcode' : 67890})
>>> array.append({'id' : 123 , 'number' : 3 , 'zipcode' : 67890})
>>> array.append({'id' : 123 , 'number' : 34 , 'zipcode' : 67890})
>>> array.append({'id' : 123 , 'number' : 3456 , 'zipcode' : 67890})
>>> array.sort(key=lambda item: item['number'], reverse=True)
>>> array
[{'zipcode': 67890, 'number': 3456, 'id': 123}, {'zipcode': 67890, 'number': 345, 'id': 123}, {'zipcode': 67890, 'number': 34, 'id': 123}, {'zipcode': 67890, 'number': 3, 'id': 123}]
```

Can you post your code?

Comment: I thank you, my problem was that i had strings instead of integers so it sorted strings.

Answer (score -1):

It works fine to me:

```
In [39]: x
Out[39]: 
[{'id': 123, 'number': 345, 'zipcode': 67890},
{'id': 12, 'number': 35, 'zipcode': 6789},
{'id': 1211, 'number': 15, 'zipcode': 1789},
{'id': 90103, 'number': 1045, 'zipcode': 79890}]

In [40]: sorted(x, key=lambda k:k['number'], reverse=True)
Out[40]: 
[{'id': 90103, 'number': 1045, 'zipcode': 79890},
{'id': 123, 'number': 345, 'zipcode': 67890},
{'id': 12, 'number': 35, 'zipcode': 6789},
{'id': 1211, 'number': 15, 'zipcode': 1789}]

In [41]: x.sort(key=lambda k:k['number'], reverse=True)

In [42]: x
Out[42]: 
[{'id': 90103, 'number': 1045, 'zipcode': 79890},
{'id': 123, 'number': 345, 'zipcode': 67890},
{'id': 12, 'number': 35, 'zipcode': 6789},
{'id': 1211, 'number': 15, 'zipcode': 1789}]
```